# need to remove [null] from array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => [null] [1] => [null] [2] => [null] [3] => [null] [4] => [null] [5] => [null] [6] => [null] [7] => [null] [8] => [null] [9] => [null] [10] => [{"SL":"2","S":"34","M":"4","L":"5","F":"5"}] [11] => [{"SL":"5","S":"3","M":"4","L":"5","F":"0"}] )
```

need output:

```
Array([0]=>[{"SL":"2","S":"34","M":"4","L":"5","F":"5"}] [1]=>[{"SL":"5","S":"3","M":"4","L":"5","F":"0"}])
```

Comment: instead of removing protect to insert null

Comment: SO is not a free coding service, we are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help you with issues you ran into when attempting so solve things yourself. So go, start yourself, then, if you cannot solve an issue, _then_ is the time to ask on SO and post your own code with a precise description what exactly you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array filter function `array_filter()` to exclude null value.

```
 array_filter($Array, function($val) { return $val !== null; })
```

Comment: Why do you test against the empty string if you want to filter out `null`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('abc',NULL,'rre',null,null,null,'dfg','fggh');

$emptyRemoved = remove_empty($arr);

function remove_empty($array) {
  return array_filter($array, '_remove_empty_internal');
}

function _remove_empty_internal($value) {
  return !empty($value) || $value === 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are handling an array of string then you can do simple array filter and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For filter only "null" values you can use array_filter without callback. For create new keys (0..n), use array_values (because array_filter preserve keys)
Result code:

```
$result = array_values(array_filter($yourArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hook:

```
array_filter($arr, function($var){return !is_null($var);} );
```

Comment: $szval=array([0] => [null] [1] => [null] [2] => [null] [3] => [null] [4] => [null] [5] => [null] [6] => [null] [7] => [null] [8] => [null] [9] => [null] [10] => [{"SL":"2","S":"34","M":"4","L":"5","F":"5"}] [11] => [{"SL":"5","S":"3","M":"4","L":"5","F":"0"}]);
foreach($pzsize as $key=>$value){
 if($value != "[null]"){
    $szval[]= $value;
 }
}

Comment: @Shakif without looping php function give you result in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$linksArray = array('1',NULL,'2',null,null,null,'3','4');
foreach($linksArray as $link)
{
if($link == '')
{
    unset($link);
}
}
print_r($linksArray);
```